# ORACLE edit columns if another column meets specific condition

Tags: oracle

I want to edit the value of several columns if a specific column contains some text.

What I am thinking of is something on these lines:

```
CASE  WHEN my_key_col like '%mystring%'
                          THEN col_1 NULL,
                               col_2 NULL,
                        ELSE
    col_1,
    col_2
END
```

This obviously doesn't work and I am not an expert with SQL. How should I approach the problem?

Comment: Can you share some sample data and what you'd want to update it to?

Comment: What do you mean by 'edit'? Are you trying to update the data in your table, or prevent not-null values being inserted in the first place, or just changing the values returned in a query? I *think* the latter but it isn't clear. Please update your question to explain what you are trying to do, preferably with examples.

Comment: @AlexPoole I need to change the values returned in a query. Will try to clarify the question

Answer (score 2):

> I need to change the values returned in a query

You can't change multiple columns in one case expression; you'll need to repeat it:

```
SELECT
  my_key_col,
  CASE WHEN my_key_col like '%mystring%' THEN NULL ELSE col1 END AS col1,
  CASE WHEN my_key_col like '%mystring%' THEN NULL ELSE col2 END AS col2
FROM ...
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kqLLYK-L)

Answer (score 1):

You can update only some of there rows using usual `WHERE`

```sql
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET col_1 = 'new_val1', col_2 = 'new_val_2'
WHERE my_key_col like '%mystring%'
```